# How to set pagination to work with '/page/'?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am trying to insert pagination links into my custom post loop. However, whenever I click on a button to go to the next page it goes to a url like: `http://example.com/services/property-portfolio/page/2`. This just takes me to the first loop of posts. I tried doing `http://example.com/services/property-portfolio/2` and that worked. How can I resolve this issue?

Beginning of loop:

```
<?php
                        $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'properties',
                            'posts_per_page' => 5,
                            'paged' => $paged
                        );
                        $carousel_num = 0;
                        $query = new WP_Query($args);

                        if ( $query->have_posts()) {

                            while ($query->have_posts() ) {
                                $query->the_post();
                                $id = get_the_ID();
                                $count = 0;
                                if(have_rows('images')):
                                    while(have_rows('images')): the_row();
                                        $count++;
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the pagination format is `/something/page/2/`, the query var is `paged`.

`page` is the query var for singular post pagination in the format `/something/2/`.